# Network Manager doesn't work

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

Dear askubuntu community,

I have a problem with my ubuntu installation that prevents me from going online. I am not the proest of Linux users and after researching, trying out different thing and failing, I decided to ask you. Maybe you can help.

1. Setup: I have a MacBook Pro (2016) with dual boot. And I am using the ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa Beta version. Since I had the exact same problem with Mint 19.3 (except my phone hotspot worked), I dare say that I do not think the problem arises from the Beta status of the OS. I am also not able (in both) to use my touchpad, but that's for another day.
2. The problem: I can install ubuntu without any major problems, while using an external mouse. I can, however, not access the internet. When I enter my password, I will be prompted again and again to authenticate.
3. Self diagnosis: After researching and trying out, I found out, that the network manager is not working.

   ```
   fub@fub:~/Desktop$ systemctl status NetworkManager.service
   ● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-04-09 06:14:40 EDT;
   36s ago
   Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Process: 6468 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 6468 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Apr 09 06:14:40 fub systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is >
   Apr 09 06:14:40 fub systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
   Apr 09 06:14:40 fub systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
   Apr 09 06:14:40 fub systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
   Apr 09 06:14:40 fub systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
   ```
4. Tried solutions: I tried to activate the Network Manager, but it failed.

   ```
   fub@fub:~/Desktop$ sudo service network-manager start
   Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
   See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
   ```

And I tried to reinstall it. I downloaded it, while in macOS and put it on a USB stick. Also didn't work.

```
fub@fub:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i das_hier_network-manager_1.22.10-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 149231 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack das_hier_network-manager_1.22.10-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking network-manager (1.22.10-1ubuntu1) over (1.22.10-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up network-manager (1.22.10-1ubuntu1) ...
Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Processing triggers for systemd (245.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Furthermore, I tried to reinstall ubuntu, but during the installation I already had the error.
```

5. Despair: I don't know, where to go from here. Can you help? I'd really appreciate it since I want to try to use Linux in my every-day life, due to it's awesomeness.

Thank you, best and stay healthy

fil

Edit: "**journalctl -xe**":

```
    fub@fub:~$ journalctl -xe
    -- The unit NetworkManager.service has entered the 'failed' state
    with result 'exit-code'.
    Apr 09 11:40:06 fub systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
    -- Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    -- 
    -- A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a         
    failure.
    -- 
    -- The job identifier is 3197 and the job result is failed.
    Apr 09 11:40:06 fub systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled 
    restart job, restart counter is at 5.
    -- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The first part, _systemctl status NetworkManager.service_ ist already up there. I'm not versed enough to know what to do, when I read that. I'm not even sure it states, how I can tackle the problem. I edited the post to include _journalctl -xe_. I have no idea, what I can get out if it...

Comment: Not sure about the function of the pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/txc4GpgZJt/

Comment: `sudo /usr/sbin/NetworkManager -d `

Comment: `fub@fub:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/NetworkManager -d
[sudo] password for fub: 
Failed to read configuration: /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi.scan-rand-mac-address.conf: Key file contains line “” which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment`

Comment: `fub@fub:~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi.scan-rand-mac-address.conf 


fub@fub:~$ `

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file contains the global configuration option:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

If not, add that global configuration to NetworkManager.conf and remove (or move, rename) the file */etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/wifi.scan-rand-mac-address.conf*

Then try starting NetworkManager.

Check your Wifi Settings Settings>WiFi>Visible Networks (SSID)>Settings.  Make sure the boxes for "Connect Automatically" and "Make Available for other users" are checked.[image]

Comment: Thank you. That worked, the Network Manager is running now. The authentication prompt when I want to enter a WiFi is still there, though. I'm ready to just give up, albeit sad

Comment: See my edited answer for other things to check.